# Shell script to Translate the find third word separated by tab in a line

Tags: regex, perl, shell, unix

Could someone please help me write ascript to translate the third word in each line, words being separated by tabs.

Sample input:

```
Hello how Are You
Iam Fine how about
```

Sample output:

```
Hello how Ziv You
Iam Fine sld about
```

The third word in each line should be translated as if using: `tr '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz]' '[zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba]'`

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in there - a second `q` instead of a `w` - or is that intentional?

Answer (score 3):

Given the following:

```
[somedude@dev7 ~]# cat so.txt 
Hello   how Are You
Iam Fine    how about
[somedude@dev7 ~]#
```

I'd run:

```
[somedude@dev7 ~]# cat so.sh 
#!/bin/bash

_INPUT="Hello how Are You
Iam Fine how about"

# read each line from config file
while read -r l 
do

  _GET_THIRD_WORD=$(echo $l | awk '{print $3}')

  echo $_GET_THIRD_WORD | sed -i "s,$_GET_THIRD_WORD,SOMETHINGTOTRANSLATEWITH," 

done < so.txt
[somedude@dev7 ~]#
```

This will echo out each of your translated lines to standard out.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -ra A; do
    printf "%s\t%s" "${A[0]}" "${A[1]}"
    printf "\t%s" "$(echo "${A[2]}" | tr '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz]' '[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba]')" "${A[@]:3}"
    echo
done
```

Run as:

```
bash script.sh < input_file
```

Output:

```
Hello   how     Aiv     You
Iam     Fine    slw     about
```

If you change `\t` to space ():

```
Hello how Ziv You
Iam Fine slw about
```

Another version:

```
#!/bin/bash
F=({A..Z} {a..z}) R=({Z..A} {z..a})
while read -ra A; do
    printf "%s\t%s" "${A[0]}" "${A[1]}"
    printf "\t%s" "$(IFS=''; echo "${A[2]}" | tr "[${F[*]}]" "[${R[*]}]")" "${A[@]:3}"
    echo
done
```

Comment: Getng Error:bash script.sh < File
Hello   howscript.sh: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<<<'
script.sh: command substitution: line 1: `tr '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz]' '[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba]' <<< "${A[2]}"'
                You
Iam     Finescript.sh: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<<<'
script.sh: command substitution: line 1: `tr '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz]' '[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba]' <<< "${A[2]}"'
     about

Comment: The typo in the question seems to have permeated to yours and all the other answers.  Instead of spelling out the whole alphabet in the `tr` expression, I think I would do this instead for reliability:  `fwd=$(eval "echo {a..z} {A..Z}"); rev=$(eval "echo {z..a} {Z..A}")` then the tr expression can be `tr "[${fwd// /}]" "[${rev// /}]")`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma That could be although you no longer have to use eval e.g. `rev=$(echo {a..z} {A..Z})`. Also I'd prefer to use arrays. See my edit. I remember trying `{a..z}` when I was making this script (as I didn't want to type A-Z a-z manually) but I'm not sure how it didn't work at that time. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, the array approach is definitely more elegant, though I think you'll need a recent bash.  It does work on 4.2.25 but not on  3.00.15.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Brace expansion works on 3.0, and arrays are already around at least since 2.05b.

Comment: Yes- you're right - I guess I typed it wrong before - I was not familiar with the brace expansion into an array - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is very kludgy but gets the job done (in the bash shell). It uses sed's `y` transliterate operator on the entire input file. This is passed via process substitution to awk and the third field stored in an array. Awk then loops through the original file and replaces each instance of the third field with the transliterated value.

```
awk -F'\t'  -v OFS='\t' 'NR == FNR{a[NR]=$3; next};{$3=a[FNR]; print}' \
<(sed -e 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz/zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba/' \
-e 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ/ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA/' file) file
```

Comment: Getting Error : awk -F'\t'  -v OFS='\t' 'NR == FNR{a[NR]=$3; next};{$3=a[FNR]; print}' \
> <(sed -e 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz/zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba/' \
> -e 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ/ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA/'MPACTS) MPACTS
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
sed: command garbled: y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ/ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA/MPACTS

Answer (score 1):

AWK script something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    IFS="\t"                                        #input field separator as tab
    CHARSET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"      
}

{
    rep_str=""                                      #replacement string
    # loop in through each char of third word
    for(i=1;i<=length($3);i++){
        char = substr($3,i,1)
        loc = index(CHARSET,tolower(char))

        #check to see if the character is actually an alphabet
        if(loc>0){

            #get the reverse location of char in the CHARSET                               
            rep_char = substr(CHARSET,27-loc,1)    

            #change the replacement character to upper case if the original char is uppercase
            if(char~/[A-Z]/){
                rep_char = toupper(rep_char)   
            }
        }else{
            rep_char = char
        }
        rep_str=rep_str rep_char                       #final replacement sting formed by concatenation of replaced char rep_char 
    }
    $3 = rep_str                                           
    print $0    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '$F[3] =~ tr/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz/ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba/ ; print "@F"' Filename
```

Comment: `$F[2]`. It's the _third_ word to be changed, and perl arrays are zero-based.